# Cygwin installation note:Hand installation over to elevated child process

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, cygwin

I am attempting to install `Cygwin` as a precursor to installing `gcc 6.3.0` on a `Windows 10` 64-bit machine.  I am following instructions I found [here](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/).

When I use the following line to install `Cygwin` packages (Step 2 at the above link):

```
C:\cygwin64>setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

I receive the following message in the Windows command window:

```
C:\cygwin64>note: Hand installation over to elevated child process.
_
```

The cursor is positioned under the `C` in `C:\cygwin64` as shown above and is flashing.  It has remained that way for approximately one hour.

Does this simply mean that the computer is taking a long time to install `Cygwin` packages.  Or does it mean the `Cygwin` installation has failed and I need to try something else?  Or is the computer waiting for me to type something into the Windows command window from the keyboard?  If the third possibility is the case, what am I supposed to type?

The instructions at the link above seem to be quite thorough, but do not mention this message.  Nor can I locate any suggestions by searching the internet.  The instructions also suggest the installation may take as little as 15 minutes.  So, after waiting an hour I am thinking there is something wrong.

Thank you for any advice.

**PS.**

I did find a message [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2013-11/msg00026.html).

that kind of seems to suggest the `Cygwin` installation was successful:

```
if the elevation was successful.  In that case the stdout log now prints

  note: Hand installation over to elevated child process.
```

But if that is the case why does the directory not reappear in the Windows command window like this: `C:\cygwin64>` instead of simply having the cursor flashing on a new line without the directory displayed?

Comment: This described exactly what I saw. I pressed the enter key and then the Command Prompt returned to normal. Thanks for your post @Mark Miller!

Answer (score 4):

After waiting approximately three hours I decided to assume the above message mentioning the elevated child process meant everything was fine even though the folder never reappeared in the Windows command window.  I proceeded with the installation of `gcc 6.3.0` using the `cygwin64` terminal and closed the Windows command window.  After completing all of the installation steps outlined within the instructions at the first link in my question post above I obtained the correct answer to the suggested test using the file `test.cpp`.  Therefore, I appear to now have a function installation of the latest version of `gcc` on the Windows 10 64-bit machine.  For that reason I decided to go ahead and post this as an answer instead of adding it to my question.